# Android establish HTTPSConnection with certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl, android-studio, https

I am developing an Android application under Android Studio and I need to establish HTTPS connection. So far I've succeeded, but with current implementation I am trusting all hosts, which could easily lead to man-in-the-middle attack. So I was wondering is there a way to trust an exact certificate and no other? So far my code looks like this:

```
    /**
* Trust every server - dont check for any certificate
*/
private void trustAllHosts() {
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }
    }};

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I am using `HttpsURLConnection` like this:

```
    private void postText(String URLAddress) {
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(URLAddress);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            boolean First = true;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if(First)
                    First=false;
                else
                    response.append("\n");
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            RequestResponse=response.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What should I do to be able to trust only the certificate that I want? What information for that certificate do I need and what I must use in order to achive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the verification yourself the easy part is to pin the public key. But then you have to think about the revocation and then your problems starts.

Why not simply using a certificate trusted by the device?

Comment: What do you mean by "pin the public key"? As for the question - my company uses some certificate that is signed by a CA that is not trusted by android(as far as I understood) and I need to explicitly say that I trust it. When I accessed the website of the company from my pc Chrome said that everything is OK with the certificate, but when I accessed the site from my phone with Chrome, it said that the certificate is not trusted. And accessing it from my app, it throws exception.

Comment: for the pinning see the answer from @steffen but keep in mind than the revocation will be painful (an heartbleed is never far away...)

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do to be able to trust only the certificate that I want?

The process of trusting only a specific certificate or public key is called certificate pinning or public key pinning. Since I don't want to repeat all the good information which already exist: please head over to the specific [article at OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) which also includes [sample code for Android](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#Android).
And in case this link goes down or moves - just search for [android certificate pinning example](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+certificate+pinning+example).

Comment: you should include the sample if possible, in case the website goes down

Comment: @Tom: It is very unlikely that OWASP goes down. It is more likely that they update they code there when needed.

Comment: keeping the link is mandatory for attribution and useful in case of updates. OWASP will probably not goes down in a short time but url can changes. In case of doubts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer The useful part ( code to achieve pinning ) is clearly missing

Comment: @Tom: I've added an easy way to find what is needed in case the link goes down. But for me it makes no sense to include the full example here. It is much better left there in the context of the original site since this context also refers to additional information like an even more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to verify the *identity* of the *subject* of the certificate as being the identity that is *authorized* to be connected to, rather than abuse the *authentication* process as you are doing by trusting a single *certificate,* which among other things gives you a problem at renewal time.

At the SSL level this is done by installing a handshake listener.

At the HTTPS level this is done by installing a `HostnameVerifier`.